# How can we compute power spectral density ($P_n$) in Weiner filter?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an image which  I corrupted with white gaussian noise in order to have SNR (Signal to noise - ratio) 10 dB . I want to apply Weiner filter to image which has noise . If I want to compute Pf I have to do this subtraction : $$P_f = P_g - P_n$$

My problem that I don't know how to compute $P_n(u,v)$. Is it possible to explain me the mathematical procedure in order to find $P_n(u,v)$ ?

**Weiner filter function :**
$$
\frac{Pf(u,v)}{Pf(u,v) + Pn(u,v)}
$$

$P_n$ : **power density spectrum of white gaussian noise**

$P_f$ : **power density spectrum of original image**

**$P_g$ function** :
$$
P_g(u,v)\approx {\left | X(u,v) \right |^{2}} / {N^{2}} 
$$
**$N$ :number of pixels**

**$|X(u,v)|$ : magnitude of DFT (corrupted noisy image)**
$$
{\left | X(u,v) \right |^{2}}
$$

**Matlab code:**

```
clear ;clc;close all;
I = imread("lenna.jpg");
I=rgb2gray(I);
rows=length(I(:,1));
colums=length(I(1,:));
N=length(I(1,:));

%Add gaussian noise SNR=10 db.
x=double(I)/255;
vi=var(x(:));%Compute variance of original image
Ig = imnoise(I,'gaussian',0,vi/10);%Add gaussian noise SNR=10 db.
Pg=(abs(fft2(Ig)).^2)/(N^2);
```

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  [Matlab has an interesting application of the Wiener filter to images](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/deblurring-images-using-a-wiener-filter.html) perhaps that will give some hints. Generally, asking for code to implement a specific thing is off-topic for this site. If you have any more specific questions, please edit your question and I'll reopen.

Comment: @Peter K. Thanks for your answer.I edit my question.Could you explain me How to compute Pn mathimatically

Answer (score 1):

When the noise is as you've used:

> `imnoise(I,'gaussian', 0, vi/10)`

and there is no blurring, then [these notes](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/VELDHUIZEN/node15.html) suggest that the Wiener filter is just

$$ G(u,v) = \frac{P_f(u,v)}{P_f(u,v) + \sigma_n^2}$$

So effectively, you'd have

$$ P_n(u,v) = \sigma_n^2 $$

Comment: I know that SNR =Pf/Pn (and Pn=σ^2 as you metioned).But my problem is that i dont have Pn(I can only compue the power spectrum density of image+noine).So how is it possible to compute Pn or σ^2 ?

Comment: @GeorgeYiannikas Your line `imnoise(I,'gaussian', 0, vi/10)` defines $\sigma^2_n$ to be `vi/10`.

Answer (score 1):

By definition white noise is flat across the spectrum, regardless of what pdf it has (i.e., Gaussian, a Poisson process generating impulses, whatever).

So *by definition* $P_n(u, v) = \sigma_n^2$, where $\sigma_n$ is power spectral density of the noise.